# Rails jobs and Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

Ive just installed redis and sidekiq on my app,

I Have a job to update a field on the users table when called upon,

And a job that sends an email once a week to all users.

Now if i boot up sidekiq with `bundle exec sidekiq` The job to update the users field fires off and completes but the email job stays in the enqueued section.

But if i boot it up with `bundle exec sidekiq -q workers -q mailers` Which i got from the Sidekiq github page only the mail jobs get completed and the others stay in the enqueued section.

Is there a command to be able to run both? Ive only started to learn about sidekiq and redis yesterday so sorry if this a stupid question,

I have the `activejob.que_adaptar` set to `sidekiq` in application.rb.

This is how i have my sidekiq worker for the User job  set up:

```
class DeactivateUser
 include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform
   User.active.update_all(active: false)
  end

end
```

Thanks.

Comment: Likely the problem is that you aren't listing 'default' as a queue to process.

Comment: Hi @MikePerham, Thanks for the reply, Do i also need to list the 'mailer' queue on for the mailer job? Its weird you've replied as i only just watched a lecture you gave on sidekiq a couple of days back!

Comment: You need to list whichever queues you want to process.  I would just send all jobs to default, why add extra queues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Oskar configured, follow the same approach to have multiple queues processed by single sidekiq process. In addition, you have to mention the queue name in the worker file. So that the sidekiq process will get the jobs from redis of that queue. For ex: ( `sidekiq_options queue: :mailers` )

```
class WORKER_NAME
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: :<queue_name>

   def perform
     ... # your work
   end
end
```

If you want to start process only listening to one queue mailers and having concurrency 10, please start like this.

`bundle exec sidekiq -c 10 -C config/myapp_sidekiq.yml -q mailers -q queue1 -q queue2`

This will listen to total of 3 queues named `mailers`, `queue1`, `queue2`. This is how you will have to start the sidekiq. For more documentation, please [refer to this](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options).

Comment: Hi thanks for replying! So when running this command `bundle exec sidekiq -c 10 -C config/myapp_sidekiq.yml -q mailers -q queue1 -q queue2 ` This will tell sidekiq to look for jobs on redis in the queues "mailers" "queue1" and "queue2" correct? This command -c 10 Is this saying how many jobs to run at once? Thanks and sorry again if i'm not quite getting this

Comment: `-c 10` is the concurrency. How many threads to run. not how many jobs. Though the same but the meaning is different.

Comment: Please accept someone's answer so that others will know that solution is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Create `config/sidekiq.yml` with list of your queues and run `sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml`.

```
    #config/sidekiq.yml

    ---
    :concurrency: 5
    :queues:
      - default
      - mailers
      - orders
```